# How to convert a linear equation system to matrix?

Tags: javascript, gaussian, linear-equation

So Im currently writing a chemical reaction solver with JavaScript, where my reaction to equalize is x<sub>1</sub>
C<sub>3</sub>H<sub>5</sub>N<sub>3</sub>O<sub>9</sub> = x<sub>2</sub> CO<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub> H<sub>2</sub>O + x<sub>4</sub> N<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>5</sub> O<sub>2</sub>.
So my linear equations would be:

3x<sub>1</sub> = x<sub>2</sub>
5x<sub>1</sub> = 2x<sub>3</sub>
3x<sub>1</sub> = 2x<sub>4</sub>
9x<sub>1</sub> = 2x<sub>2</sub> + x<sub>3</sub> + 2x<sub>5</sub>

Now I found a JavaScript [code on Github](https://github.com/itsravenous/gaussian-elimination/blob/master/gauss.js) to perform the Gaussian Elimination on linear equation systems. However, this function takes a matrix A as an input as well as a vector x. But I, who never had to do something with matrices, dont know how to convert the previously mentioned equations into a matrix A, and I also dont know what is meant by the input vector x.

Comment: Look at https://github.com/itsravenous/gaussian-elimination/blob/master/example.js to understand how this program is used, how the matrix correlates to the equation.

Comment: To clairfy, do you know how the Gaussian Elimination works, and do you know how to multiply vectors with matrices? If I'm right, you are asking for help for a mathematical question, an not a js-based one?